# How to get tokens for the Assassin quest?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm playing a Rogue and I want to use the Assassin Specialization, but I finished the Crestwood zone before taking the specialization quest.

How i can take the guild leader tokens now ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your title formulated as such :s moreover, you talk about "Bandits Mark" in the title of the question but not in the question itself. Can you reformulate it or be more precise ?

Comment: I need the "3 assassin guild leader tokens"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find them in different places, [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718650-dragon-age-inquisition/70621261) is the best I could find :

> Target 1 (Flats Target) - dwarf- head towards the Astrarium by Old Crestwood, if your approaching from the Flats you will bump right into him
>
> Target 2 (Black Fens) - Human male - He is pretty close to the dragon ... so watch out. He is just North Westish from the dragon, by the quarry if you already discovered it.
>
> Target 3 (East Hill) - Human Female - This one was annoying as hell to find, but she is really by the docks ... just not the ones you are probably thinking of. North West of (new) Crestwood is a small lake that has a dock and a fishermans hut. She will be just outside.
>
> For the book just look next to Cole, it is right next to him ... don't need to do any fancy conversation friend BS. If you didn't recruit Cole, the book will be at the Val Royeax book merchant.

Comment: I already killed all the bandits in Crestwood before the i take the quest. So i dont have more bandits to kill.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it again ? And if you did it already then you must have the items on you.

Comment: I will check this...

Comment: I was able to find the tokens by saving near a camp where assassins spawn in the Western Approach, and reloading the save to farm tokens. I started with 2/3, took about 15 minutes to get the third.
http://i.imgur.com/akVp8CD.jpg